# Rails include params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create a new task, I get the following parameters

```
  Parameters: {"plan_task"=>{"name"=>"123123", "owner_id"=>"1", "wbs"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create", "project_id"=>"project-1"}
```

So now i want to know how i can include the project_id into the plan_task params

```
def plan_task_params
  params.require(:plan_task).permit(:name, :owner_id, :wbs, :description)
end
```

Can you help me with  that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
def plan_task_params
  params.permit(:commit, :project_id, plane_task: [:name, :owner_id, :wbs, :description])
end
```

it will give you:

```
Parameters: { "commit"=>"Create", "project_id"=>"project-1", "plan_task"=>{"name"=>"123123", "owner_id"=>"1", "wbs"=>"", "description"=>""}}
```